# clearing session values on browser close

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I wanted to `clear session values on browser close`.So i used the below code

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
window.onbeforeunload = WindowCloseHanlder;
function WindowCloseHanlder()
{
  location.href = 'clear_session.aspx'
}
</script>
```

In the above code am using a function which determines the closing of the tab of a browser.This code is working fine in IE 8,9,10 and Firefox.But the same code is not working in chrome.I need to know the tab close event in chrome had tried the below code also

```
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function (windowId) {
        alert("!! Exiting the Browser !!");
    });
```

Here am using the chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener to determine the tab closed event in javascript.
    For the above code that is chrome.windows do we need to include any API.Can you please provide the code to determine close event of the tab in Google chrome..

Comment: This could be helpful: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/227382/Alert-Session-Time-out-in-ASP-Net

Answer (score 2):

Sessions are usualy used for this. According to Wikipedia, when no expiration date is set, a cookie is cleared when the user closes the browser.

***The cookie setter can specify a deletion date, in which case the cookie will be removed on that date. If the cookie setter does not specify a date, the cookie is removed once the user quits his or her browser.***

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery then try the cross browser solution.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
//Let jQuery take care of detecting browser and implement
  WindowCloseHanlder();
});
```

Handy syntax

```
$(window).on('beforeunload',WindowCloseHanlder);
```

Comment: this code window.onbeforeunload = function () { return "Are you sure"; }; works in chrome but not possible to clear session values.The above code does not work in chrome it works in IE and firefox only